# Testing the interaction of two pages with FuncUnit

Tags: jquery, testing, funcunit

I want to test the interaction of two pages (opened by different users, but there are no cookies). Can I do that with FuncUnit?

Obviously calling `S.open()` twice doesn't result in having *both* pages open. I also tried `S.sub()`, but that's not defined.

If FuncUnit can't do it, is there any lightweight free testing tool that can?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the two pages in [frames](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) and use the [context parameter](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!funcunit.finding) in queries.